# Sound randomly turning down windows 7

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, audio

What happends:

i am listening to music on a youtube playlist and at random points during many songs the sound goes down (not because its shoddy quality trying to avoid copyright its official vevo and from the original artists)

temp fix:

if the sound goes down i pause the video and the sound returns to normal

When does the error occur:

this happens when: the site reloads (every time it change song it will load up a new page and the sound goes down) and also if i turn on the sound on youtube (the sound is on 90% i turn up to 100 and it sounds like it goes down to 80 and feels less like it has less power)

software:
Using windows 7, Google Chrome, 
Hardware:

Steel Series Siberia 2 (from somewhere around 2010)

Notes:

I do not know if it occurs on other browsers but i would rather have a fix than be redirected to another browser,
I do know my headset is old and may have suffered some damage but i dont think the problem is cause by the headset unless its some factory error i just dont know of

Answer (score 0):

Youtube stores it's audio settings client-side in the form of cookies so that you have the same audio settings for every video on a given computer.  Press Ctrl + Shift + Del and clear out "Cookies and other side plugin data" and make sure the dropdown menu is set to at least as far back as you remember the problem occurring.
*WARNING: This will delete active logins and other site data, if there are any site-specific settings you wanted to keep then this is the nuclear option.*

Otherwise, to find the specific cookie that stores Youtube volume data go to Chrome's **Settings**, click the button that says **Show advanced settings...**, under privacy find **Content Settings...** followed by **All cookies and site data..."**.  In the searchbox type *youtube*, the cookie you want will be labeled under the site *www.youtube.com* **-not "youtube.com"-** and under "Locally stored data" it will say *local storage*, delete all cookies that match this description by clicking the little X on the right.

Comment: hey i have been using alot of time making sure that all coockies are eleminated and there should be none on my computer but i still have the issue